# Opencl buffer with already deleted host pointer

Tags: c++, opencl

I have a situation where I (might) want to try using a `std::vector` (or more precisely its storage) as host pointer for an opencl `buffer` object with `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`. This has obviously problems if the `vector` is resized and therefore reallocates its memory. The modifications to my `vector` are during phases of the program, where the `buffer` is not used, so my idea is that I check if the host pointer of the buffer is identical to the pointer to the first element of the `vector` and recreate the buffer if that is not the case. My problem is that I haven't been able to find out if it is legal to have a `buffer`, for which the host-pointer has already been deallocated, if the `buffer` isn't used.

I could of course destroy the buffer at the end of the phase where it is used, however I don't know in advance if the vector contents and/or length are modified and if they aren't I would rather keep the old buffer, since afaik that would enable it to stay cached on the device, reducing the amout of data needed to be transferred over the pci-e bus.

**My question is**: Is it allowed to have an opencl `buffer` with `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` for which the host pointer has already host pointer been deleted, if the `buffer` object only exists, but isn't used in a kernel.

For the record I'm currently developing against nvidias opencl implementation, using a Tesla 2070 as a gpu and the software will probably be ported to amd gpus/cpus in the near future (the later being the main reason to use `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`). So if the answer is implementation specific, those are the primary targets, though I'm really more interested in the general answer, since I don't know what else it will run on at later times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would be safer if you did not try to change the buffer underneath the OpenCL implementation.  As you suggested this would likely bring problems.  For instance:

```
vector<int> v(25);
cl_mem buf = clCreateBuffer(.v.data(),.CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,...);
v.resize(1000); //Or some other way of changing the size of the stack
clReleaseMemObject(buf);
```

When the memory is released it will attempt to sync the data back to the original buffer (which has been deallocated) likely causing a segfault or some other nasty memory problems.

According to some discussion on [this thread](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=4145#wrapheader), it should be assumed that as soon as you call the clCreateBuffer with the `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` flag that you have ceded control of that memory to the OpenCL platform and you can only reclaim that memory with a call to release that memory buffer.

While it is possible that in your specific implementation this is not the case, I would think that overall it would be advisable to release the data.  That way, if your underlying system changes in the future, you won't see a bug associated with this behavior.

Optionally, you could possibly extend the vector class such that on resizes of the underlying data structure, you could release and reallocate data on the device. I'm not sure how difficult this would be, or how much it would affect the rest of your program, though.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of. Ah well. I'll probably look into writing a custom allocator to use with `std::vector`, which manages an underlying buffer

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on what flags were used to create the buffer. If you call [clCreateBuffer](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html) with CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR or CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, then the OpenCL implementation already has a copy (in the case of CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, maybe - it ought to for GPU implementations) of the contents of the host location you provided. Now you are free to do whatever you want with that host pointer and the OpenCL implementation doesn't care.

If, on the other hand you use CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR (which I don't suppose you do or even can due to this being a GPU device) then in all probability the kernel will either crash on execution or provide junk results (based on what's in that location now).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to use `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`, forgot to mention that in the question (although I would have expected that to be clear, since that is where there could be problems). I will add that to the question. And (was that also unclear?) I don't want to call a kernel using that buffer, the question is if it can still crash, if the buffer simply exists, but isn't used

Comment: If you are using CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR on a GPU device, I don't see how the implementation would have any option but to make a copy for transfer to the GPU, so it should make no difference. According to the docs: *OpenCL implementations are allowed to cache the buffer contents pointed to by host_ptr in device memory. This cached copy can be used when kernels are executed on a device*. If the contents are cached during buffer creation time, doing anything you want to the underlying pointer should not affect the device buffer contents in GPU/driver memory.

Comment: @anathonline: I would expect it to do so some way or other (meaning that for execution of a kernel the data will probably end up in graphic memory (though I'm not sure if that is actually necessary)). That doesn't really answer the question though.

Comment: See the last sentence of my comment: **If the contents are cached during buffer creation time, doing anything you want to the underlying pointer should not affect the device buffer contents in GPU/driver memory**. And yes - for kernel execution your data **HAS** to be in GPU memory. This is also very-implementation dependent and some other CPU/GPU (say AMD's Fusion) might do something else. It would be better to use the DeviceType to determine if you're going to copy or share - this is what I do in my applications.

Comment: I don't expect it to do so, but that doesn't guarantee that it doesn't access the actual data on the host at abitrary times (e.g. writebacks). I hope that it won't, but that isn't a good idea to base the correctness on the code on). Besides there is no requirement to cache the data during creation of the buffer (and from what I've read it might not, since the gpu might be able to fetch it by itself), so doing anything to the pointer while the buffer was used is likely a bad idea. I'm just not sure if there are any guarantees that it won't access the data at arbitrary time points.

Comment: This is implementation-dependent, the OpenCL spec makes no guarantee of it and that to me means for correctness - we shouldn't be messing with host data when the bits are shared. The OpenCL documentation specifically states the implementation is allowed to cache data from this location, so we can't assume it wont, either. I also don't understand your insistence that the buffer data is not copied/cached by the driver when using a GPU device. AFAIK there is no way for a GPU to address bits in CPU memory. Is there?

Comment: IIRC the gpu can fetch data from the ram autonomously, so it doesn't necessarily need a copy of the complete data (i could theoretically pull it in when needed) and might (although I really don't know about that) not actually need a local copy at all (although it is likely very useful to have one).

Comment: If you're referring to GPUDirect (http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/nvidia-gpudirect) - I'm not even sure if nVidia supports this in their OpenCL drivers. This sort of operation definitely not supported by the OpenCL spec and therefore undefined  in a cross-vendor, heterogeneous compute library such as OpenCL.